# What the heck is a dbus argument of type a{sa{sv}} in the Network Manager API?

Tags: format, variadic-functions, dbus, method-signature, networkmanager

I'm looking through the dbus api for Network Manager and there are methods with inputs of type `a{sa{sv}}`.
I'm still new to dbus but if I'm interpreting the definition of signature specifiers in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_bus_message_read.html# correctly this is:

- A variable-length array

  - Of named variable arrays

    - Of named "variants" (which I guess are tagged unions)

What practically is this for?  A name-paginated list of named settings?  I'm seeing it all over the place in this API.

Comment: Having looked at some example command line code I guess this may be a set of properties?  I guess they aren't really first class members of dbus so the object path and interface are taken up by a getter or setter method and as a result the "address" of the properties are encoded this way?   I'd like confirmation from someone who actually knows though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this is what I guess should be called a "Settings" in Network Manager.  For several methods instead of building a connection setting by setting an entire set of settings are added all at once.  Here's a tabbed and commented version of the settings of my current connection as queried for example:

```
5
    "connection" 5
        "id" s "Profile 1"
        "permissions" as o //<empty array of strings>
        "timestamp" t 1661376049
        "type" s "802-3-ethernet"
        "uuid" s <not posting for privacy>
    "802-3-ethernet" 3
        "auto-negotiate" b false
        "mac-address-blacklist" as 0
        "s390-options" a{ss} 0
    "ipv4" 6
        "address-data" aa{sv} 0
        "addresses" aau 0
        "dns-search" as 0
        "method" s "auto"
        "route-data" aa{sv} 0
        "routes" aau 0
    "ipv6" 7
        "addr-gen-mode" i 1
        "address-data" aa{sv} 0
        "addresses" a(ayuay) 0
        "dns-search" as 0
        "method" s "auto"
        "route-data" aa{sv} 0
        "routes" a(ayuayu) 0
    "proxy" 0
```

I think most of these are defaults so the real settings you might set when creating a connection are probably something like:

```
4
    "connection" 4
        "id" s "Profile Foo"
        "timestamp" t <whatever, maybe this is autogenerated>
        "type" s "802-3-ethernet"
        "uuid" s <might be auto generated too>
    "802-3-ethernet" 0
    "ipv4" 1
        "method" s "auto"
    "ipv6" 1
        "addr-gen-mode" i 1
        "method" s "auto"
```

Answer (score 2):

- `s` is `std::string`.
- `v` is `variant`.
- `a{}` is `std::map`.
- `a{sv}` is `std::map<std::string, Variant>`
- Finally: `a{sa{sv}}` is `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Variant>>`

`Variant` can hold value of any D-Bus-supported type, if you are using `c++` I recommend you to check it at 
[sdbus-cpp](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp/blob/master/include/sdbus-c%2B%2B/Types.h#L42)

Comment: I got that much.  But what the heck is a map of maps to arbitrary data used for that it's expected you'll just sling them around as a matter of course with no real explanation?  Has the API been designed so you never need intermediate state to be preserved between methods so you just cram in a whole config file and use one call?

Comment: Welcome to dbus world brother :D

Comment: I suggest you look at the NetworkManager source code or API documentation. I believe the D-Bus API for NetworkManager is probably not meant to be used directly and you‘re meant to use libnm instead.

Comment: I was looking for that.  But of course nothing was named networkmanager-dev(el)  Thanks!